# docker-machine fails to start host

Tags: macos, docker

I've recently installed docker toolbox (OS X) on my computer and although I have it working on my other laptop fine, it doesn't seem to work properly on this one. After installing using docker toolbox and launching via the docker command line tool (as per the docker docs). I get a host is not running error for some reason?

```
Machine default already exists in VirtualBox.
Starting machine default... exit status 1 Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the docker-machine env command. Setting environment variables for machine default...
                    ##         .
              ## ## ##        ==
           ## ## ## ## ##    ===
       /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
       \______ o           __/
         \    \         __/
          \____\_______/
host is not running docker is configured to use the default machine with IP For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
default is not running. Please start this with docker-machine start default
```

Trying docker-machine start default also fails to start the host:

```
bash-3.2$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM
default            virtualbox   Stopped         
bash-3.2$ docker-machine start default
exit status 1
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
bash-3.2$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM
default            virtualbox   Stopped
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an issue compatibility with Virtual Box 5.0.
Try the solutions mentioned here in this Github issue. 
[Docker not installing correctly](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15712)

Comment: Updating virtual box together with making sure the VM is deleted fixed the issue (and confirming your hardware supports intel virtualisation fixed the issue. )